# Redirect to login page

Tags: php, redirect

I want to make login page, another php page handles the request,
I want t check the validity of credential info, in a case that user name or pswd is not correct, I want to make redirection to login page, **HOW can I make redirection in php ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use '[header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)':

```
header('Location: /login.php');
```

Reminder that no data can be printed to the screen before a header() is called.

Comment: Lol, isn't this what I posted?

Answer (score 4):

Redirection in PHP is easy. Just make sure *not* to print out any HTML before you do it:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 1):

`header('Location: /path/page.php');` and `exit;`

Comment: This is incorrect. HTTP requires to give a complete URI not only the path.